# Add values of one column

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am trying to get a record by adding values of one column based on key value. Here is the query I have:

```
SELECT    
    PM_ProductPayment.ProjectId, SalesDetail.SalesPerson,
    PM_ProductCost.ProductCost, dbo.PM_ProductPayment.ProductPayment, 
    dbo.PM_ProductPayment.PaymentDate    
FROM    
    dbo.PM_ProductPayment 
INNER JOIN 
    dbo.PM_Product ON dbo.PM_ProductPayment.ProjectId = dbo.PM_Product.ProductId    
INNER JOIN 
    dbo.PM_ProductCost ON dbo.PM_ProductPayment.ProductId = dbo.PM_ProductCost.ProductId    
INNER JOIN 
    dbo.SalesDetail ON dbo.PM_Product.SalesPersonId = dbo.SalesDetail.ID
```

The result I am getting is:

[image: Output]

Now, here I want to get single row by adding "Payment" for each product and last payment date.

Please optimize my query or suggest any other better way to do that..

Thanks,

Comment: _What_ is your desired result? And please, don't post images but code that we can copy/paste. You can use the `{}`-button for formatting code in the editor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT pay.ProjectId, 
       sum(pay.ProductPayment),
       max(pay.PaymentDate) 
FROM dbo.PM_ProductPayment pay
INNER JOIN dbo.PM_Product pro ON pay.ProjectId = pro.ProductId    
INNER JOIN dbo.PM_ProductCost cos ON pay.ProductId =cos.ProductId    
INNER JOIN dbo.SalesDetail sal ON pro.SalesPersonId = sal.ID 
GROUP BY pay.ProjectId
```

Comment: Thanks juergen d. But what if I have to add one column for "Payment Remark"?